# Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$. Find the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$.

Tags: calculus

$\int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} dx$ is a Beta function.

The probability density function of the Beta distribution is given by $f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} x^{\alpha - 1} (1 - x)^{\beta - 1}$.

Therefore, $x^k (1-x)^{n-k} = B(\alpha, \beta)\frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} x^{\alpha - 1} (1 - x)^{\beta - 1}$ can be seen as the density function of a Beta distribution multiplied by $B(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\alpha = k + 1$ and $\beta = n - k + 1$.

Hence, we can rewrite the original limit as
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x \sim\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \text{Beta}(k+1, n-k+1)\mathbb{E}_{X \sim \text{Beta}(k+1, n-k+1)}[f(X)],
$$
But I don't know how to deal with it next.t_t

Answer (score 4):

We have $$ \sum_{k=0}^nx^k(1-x)^{n-k}=(1-x)^n{1-{x^{n+1}\over (1-x)^{n+1}}\over  1-{x\over 1-x}}\\
= {(1-x)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}\over 1-2x}$$ For $f(x)=(1-2x)g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is continuous for $x\neq 1/2$ and absolutely integrable, we obtain $$(n+1)\int\limits_0^1(1-x)^{n+1}g(x)\,dx\\ - (n+1)\int\limits_0^1x^{n+1}g(x)\,dx $$ The limit is equal $$g(0)-g(1) =f(0)+f(1)$$ as in general $$\lim_n(n+1)\int\limits_0^1x^nh(x)\,dx =h(1)$$ The latter follows easily from the fact that $(n+1)x^n$ tends to $0$ uniformly on each interval $[0,1-\delta]$ and $(n+1)\int\limits_0^1x^n\,dx=1.$

In general if $f(x)/|2x-1|$ is not absolutely integrable we can approximate $f(x)$ by $f_k(x)=f(x)|2x-1|^{1/k}$ for which the ratio $f_k(x)/|2x-1|$ is absolutely integrable. As $f_k(0)=f(0)$ and $f_k(1)=f(1)$ the limit is equal
$f(0)+f(1).$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x=f(0)+f(1).$$

Denote
$$I_n= n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-1-k}f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x,\qquad n\in\mathbb N_{\geq1}.$$
Using the summation formula for geometric series we obtain
$$I_n=n\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^n-x^n}{1-2x}f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x.$$
Let $x=(1+s)/2$, then
$$I_n=\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}g(s)\,\mathrm{d} s,$$
where $g(s)=f((1+s)/2)$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$, so $M:=\sup_{s\in[-1,1]}|g(s)|<+\infty$.

For each $\varepsilon\in(0,1/2)$, there exists $\delta\in(0, \varepsilon)$ such that $|g(s)-g(1)|<\varepsilon$ for all $s\in(1-\delta, 1)$ and $|g(s)-g(-1)|<\varepsilon$ for all $s\in(-1, -1+\delta)$. Now we decompose $I_n$ into several parts: let
\begin{align*}
 I_n^{(1)}&=\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{-1+\delta}^{1-\delta}\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}g(s)\,\mathrm{d} s\\
 I_n^{(2)}&=\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{-1}^{-1+\delta}\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}(g(s)-g(-1))\,\mathrm{d} s\\
 I_n^{(3)}&=\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}(g(s)-g(1))\,\mathrm{d} s\\
 I_n^{(4)}&=g(-1)\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{-1}^{-1+\delta}\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\\
 I_n^{(5)}&=g(1)\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s,
\end{align*}
then $I_n=I_n^{(1)}+I_n^{(2)}+I_n^{(3)}+I_n^{(4)}+I_n^{(5)}$. For $I_n^{(1)}$, by the mean value theorem, for any $s\in(-1+\delta, 1-\delta)$, there exists $\xi\in(-1+\delta, 1-\delta)$ such that $(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n=2n(1+\xi)^{n-1}s$, and thus
$$\left|(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n\right|\leq 2ns(2-\delta)^{n-1}, \qquad s\in(-1+\delta, 1-\delta).$$
Hence
$$\left|I_n^{(1)}\right|\leq \frac n{2^{n+1}}\cdot 2n(2-\delta)^{n-1}M\cdot 2(1-\delta)\leq Mn^2\left(\frac{2-\delta}2\right)^n\rightarrow0, \text{as }n\rightarrow\infty, $$
and thus for $n$ sufficiently large, we have $\left|I_n^{(1)}\right|\leq \varepsilon$.
For $I_n^{(j)}(2\leq j\leq 5)$, we just need to estimate
$$\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s.$$
Clearly we have
$$\int_{1-\delta}^1\left[(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n\right]\,\mathrm{d} s\leq\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\leq \frac1{1-\delta}\int_{1-\delta}^1(1+s)^n\,\mathrm{d} s,$$
hence
$$\frac{2^{n+1}-(2-\delta)^{n+1}-\delta^{n+1}}{n+1}\leq\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\leq\frac1{1-\delta} \frac{2^{n+1}-(2-\delta)^{n+1}}{n+1},$$
and then
$$1\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^{n+1}}\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{(1+s)^n-(1-s)^n}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\leq \frac1{1-\delta}.$$
So, for $n$ sufficiently large, we have
$$\left|I_n^{(2)}\right|+\left|I_n^{(3)}\right|\leq \frac{4\varepsilon}{1-\delta}\leq 8\varepsilon,$$
and
$$\left|I_n^{(4)}-g(-1)\right|+\left|I_n^{(5)}-g(1)\right|\leq 4M\left(\frac1{1-\delta}-1\right)=\frac{4M\delta}{1-\delta}\leq 8M\varepsilon.$$

Now we have shown that for each $\varepsilon\in(0,1/2)$, there holds
$$\left|I_n-(g(-1)+g(1))\right|\leq \varepsilon+8\varepsilon+8M\varepsilon=(8M+9)\varepsilon,$$
for $n$ sufficiently large. Therefore
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n=g(-1)+g(1)=f(0)+f(1).$$

Answer (score 1):

First, we prove that for any polynomial $P(x)$, the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} P(x) \mathrm{d} x =P(0)+P(1)
$$
is correct.

Without loss of generality，let $P(x)=x^m\ (m=0,1,2,\cdots)$, and we use the $\beta $ function, then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} P(x) \mathrm{d} x &=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} x^m \mathrm{d} x \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+m}\frac{1}{\displaystyle{\binom{n+m}{k+m}}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
$$
The final limit is based on the characteristic of combination, which is
$$
\binom{b}{a} \geq \frac{b(b-1)}{2}\ ,\ 2 \leq a \leq b-2
$$
We note that the polynomial space is a linear space , so for any polynomial $P(x)$, the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} P(x) \mathrm{d} x =P(0)+P(1)
$$
is established.

Secondly, we use the $weierstrass-stone$ theory, which is, for the continuous function f on the closed interval $[0,1]$, and for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, then there exsits a polynomial $P_0(x)$, satisfied
$$
\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-P_0(x)| < \varepsilon
$$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x &\leq (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} (P_0(x) + \varepsilon) \mathrm{d} x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} P_0(x) \mathrm{d} x + \varepsilon (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\binom{n}{k}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Use the characteristic of combination, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\binom{n}{k}}}=2
$$
So we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x &\leq P_0(0) + P_0(1) + 2 \varepsilon\\
&\leq f(0) + f(1) + 4 \varepsilon
\end{aligned}
$$
Use the same method, we have
$$
\varliminf_{n\to\infty}(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x \geq f(0) + f(1) +4\varepsilon
$$
Finally, let $\varepsilon \to 0$, the we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \mathrm{d} x =f(0)+f(1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\,f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\,$ be a continuous function on $\,[0,1]\,.$ Find the limit $\,\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\!.$

Since $\,f\,$ is continuous on $\,[0,1]\,,\,$ there exists $\,M>0\,$ such that $\,\left|f(x)\right|\leqslant M\;\;$ for any $\,x\in[0,1]\,.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Moreover, for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,\land\,n\geqslant3\,,\,$ it results that

$\displaystyle\left|\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant$

$\displaystyle\leqslant\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left|\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant$

$\displaystyle\leqslant\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\big|f(x)\big|\,\mathrm dx\underset{\overbrace{\;\text{ by applying }(1)\;}}{\leqslant}$

$\displaystyle\leqslant\big(n+1\big)M\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\,\mathrm dx=$

$\displaystyle=\big(n+1\big)M\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathrm{Beta}\big(k+1,n-k+1\big)=$

$\displaystyle=\big(n+1\big)M\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k!\big(n-k\big)!}{\big(n+1\big)!}=M\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{\binom nk}\underset{\overbrace{\,\text{because }\binom nk\geqslant\binom n2\\\,\text{for any}\,2\leqslant k\leqslant n-2\,}}{\leqslant}$

$\leqslant\!M\!\!\left[\dfrac1{\binom n1}+\dfrac{n-3}{\binom n2}+\dfrac1{\binom n{n-1}}\right]\!=M\!\left[\dfrac2n+\dfrac{2(n-3)}{n(n-1)}\right]\!<\dfrac{4M}n\,.$

Consequently, by applying Squeeze theorem, it follows that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\!=0\;.\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Now, we will prove that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\!=f(1)\;.$

For any $\,\varepsilon>0\,,\,$ since $\,\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)=f(1)\,,\,$ there exists $\,x_\varepsilon\in(0,1)\,$ such that $\;\big|f(x)-f(1)\big|<\dfrac\varepsilon2\;\;\;\forall x\in\left[x_\varepsilon,1\right].\quad\color{blue}{(3)}$

Moreover,
$\big|f(x)-f(1)\big|\leqslant\big|f(x)\big|+\big|f(1)\big|\leqslant2M\;\;\;\forall x\in\left[0,x_\varepsilon\right].\quad\color{blue}{(4)}$

Let $\;n_\varepsilon=\max\left\{1,\left\lfloor\dfrac{\ln\varepsilon-\ln(4M)}{\ln x_\varepsilon}\right\rfloor\!-\!1\right\}\in\Bbb N\,.$

For any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\land\,n>n_\varepsilon\,$ it results that

$2Mx_\varepsilon^{n+1}\leqslant2Mx_\varepsilon^{n_\varepsilon+2}\leqslant2Mx_\varepsilon^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\varepsilon-\ln(4M)}{\ln x_\varepsilon}\right\rfloor+1}<2Mx_\varepsilon^{\frac{\ln\varepsilon-\ln(4M)}{\ln x_\varepsilon}}=$
$=2Mx_\varepsilon^{\log_{x_\varepsilon}\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{4M}\right)}=2M\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4M}=\dfrac{\varepsilon}2\;\;,\quad\color{blue}{(5)}$

$\displaystyle\left|\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx-f(1)\right|=$

$\displaystyle=\left|\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(1)\mathrm\,dx\right|=$

$\displaystyle=\left|\int_0^1(n+1)x^n\big[f(x)-f(1)\big]\,\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant$

$\displaystyle\leqslant\int_0^1(n+1)x^n\big|f(x)-f(1)\big|\,\mathrm dx=$

$\displaystyle=\!\int_0^{x_\varepsilon}\!\!\!(n\!+\!1)x^n\big|f(x)\!-\!f(1)\big|\,\mathrm dx+\!\!\int_{x_\varepsilon}^1\!(n\!+\!1)x^n\big|f(x)\!-\!f(1)\big|\,\mathrm dx<$

$\displaystyle\underset{\overbrace{(3)\text{ and }(4)}}{<}2M\!\!\int_0^{x_\varepsilon}\!\!\!(n\!+\!1)x^n\mathrm dx+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2\!\int_{x_\varepsilon}^1\!(n\!+\!1)x^n\mathrm dx=$

$=2M\big[x^{n+1}\big]_0^{x_\varepsilon}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2\big[x^{n+1}\big]_{x_\varepsilon}^1=$

$=2Mx_{\varepsilon}^{n+1}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2\left(1-x_{\varepsilon}^{n+1}\right)\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by applying }(5)\;}}{<}\dfrac\varepsilon2+\dfrac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon\,.$

So we have proved that for any $\,\varepsilon>0\,,\,$ there exists $\,n_{\varepsilon}\in\Bbb N\,$ such that for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\land\,n>n_\varepsilon\,$ it results that
$\displaystyle\left|\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx-f(1)\right|<\varepsilon\;\,,\;\;\;\;$ that is ,

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\!=f(1)\;.\quad\color{blue}{(6)}$

Analogously, we can prove that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1x^ng(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\!=g(1)\qquad\color{blue}{(7)}$

for any continuous function $\,g\,$ on $\,[0,1]\,.$

In particular, if $\,g:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\,$ is the continuous function defined as $\,g(t)=f(1-t)\;$ for any $\,t\in[0,1]\,,\,$ by applying the change of variable $\,t=1-x\,$ in the following definite integral, we get that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1(1-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]=$

$\displaystyle=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1t^nf(1-t)\,\mathrm dt\right]\!=$

$\displaystyle=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1t^ng(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]\!=g(1)=f(1-1)=f(0)\;.$

Consequently ,

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\int_0^1(1-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]=f(0)\;.\quad\color{blue}{(8)}$

From $\,(8)\,,\,$ $(2)\,$ and $\,(6)\,,\,$ it follows that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\left[\big(n+1\big)\!\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]=f(0)+f(1)\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with the supremum norm $\|f\| := \sup_{[0,1]} |f|$.

**Observation 1.** The combined contribution from the terms for $0 < k < n$ is negligible. Indeed, it is well-known that

$$ I^{(n)}_{k} := (n+1) \int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}. $$

From this and the basic properties of the binomial coefficient, we observe that

\begin{gather*}
I^{(n)}_{1} = I^{(n)}_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
I^{(n)}_{k} \leq \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} \quad \text{for $2 \leq k \leq n-2$}.
\end{gather*}

Plugging this to OP's sum restricted to the range $0 < k < n$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
&\left| (n+1) \sum_{k : 0<k<n} \int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
&\qquad \leq \sum_{k : 0<k<n} \|f\| I^{(n)}_{k}
\leq \|f\| \biggl( \frac{2}{n} + \frac{n-3}{\binom{n}{2}} \biggr)
\to 0.
\end{align*}

**Observation 2.** When $k = n$, the substitution $y = x^{n+1}$ gives

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{1} f(y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}) \, \mathrm{d}y
\to \int_{0}^{1} f(1) \, \mathrm{d}y
= f(1),
\end{align*}

where we can utilize the dominated convergence theorem (or the standard *approximation-to-the-identity* argument) to justify the limit step. By a similar argument, when $k = 0$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} (n+1) (1-x)^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \to f(0).
\end{align*}

**Conclusion.** Combining altogether, we conclude:

$$ \bbox[border:1px dotted navy;padding:5px;color:navy;]{\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(0) + f(1)} $$

---

**Addendum.** As per @Angelo's request, I included an elementary argument implementing approximation-to-the-identity:

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. By the continuity of $f$ at $x = 1$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(1)| \leq \varepsilon$ whenever $|x - 1| \leq \delta$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\left| \int_{0}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - f(1) \right| \\
&= \left| \int_{0}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} [f(x) - f(1)] \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
&\leq \varepsilon \left( \int_{1-\delta}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
+ 2\|f\| \left( \int_{0}^{1-\delta} (n+1) x^{n} \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&\leq \varepsilon + 2\|f\| (1-\delta)^{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Taking $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$, we get

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{0}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - f(1) \right| \leq \varepsilon. $$

Since the limsup is independent of the choice of $\varepsilon$, letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ shows that the limsup is zero. Therefore we conclude

$$ \int_{0}^{1} (n+1) x^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \to f(1). $$

Comment: This solution reminds me of that Grothendieck quote - remove all needless obfuscation and the solution will naturally reveal itself (paraphrased )!

Comment: @dezdichado, where is that Grothendieck quote? I cannot find it in this page. Could you explain better what you meant?

Comment: Sangchul Lee, please, could you write an addendum in which you prove that limit step by using the standard approximation-to-the-identity argument ? I have tried to do it but finally I obtain a very similar proof to what I wrote in my answer. Please show me how you prove that limit step.

Comment: @Angelo, Your proof is essentially how approximation-to-the-identity argument works. I added my own rendition of this argument to my answer, but you will see that it is essentially identical to yours. Anyway, specializing this to the case above, the argument works by noting that the "mass distribution" $$x \mapsto (n+1)x^n$$ concentrates about $x = 1$ as $n\to\infty$, thereby approximating the unit point mass at $x = 1$. (Here, the term "identity" refers to the fact that the point mass $\delta_0(x)$, a.k.a. Dirac delta, acts as the identity for the convolution operation.)